# SSL Certificate Verify Issue

Tags: ssl, python-requests

I have a site , and the SSL Certificate works properly when I open it using Chrome.

But when I use requests to get the URL I get the following error

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somerandomsite.subdomain.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Any way to have more verbose output on why it fails, or understand whats the issue here?

The certificate has been generated using Let's Encrypt through Google R3

Comment: Probably missing intermediate certificate or otherwise wrong server configuration. Check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

Comment: Or the server provisioning uses intermediate under the ISRG root which AIUI LE _finally_ officially 'switched on' a few months ago instead of the older DST Root (which is expiring in only 3 days!), and Chrome is using an up-to-date truststore including ISRG (depends on the platform, which wasn't identified) but (this) python has an old certifi, _or_ is configured or coded to use a different truststore which is similarly out-of-date. SSLLabs will show if server is using ISRG, but won't show what python/requests is using for truststore. (@SteffenUllrich)

Comment: See e,g, https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/